# Как с помощью Selenium искать класс определенного порядка?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

Дана подобная структура:

```
<div class='N'>
    <div class='S'></div>
    <div class='S'></div>
    <div class='S'></div>
</div>
<div class='N'>
    <div class='S'></div>
    <div class='S'></div>
</div>
<div class='N'>
    <div class='S'></div>
    <div class='S'></div>
    <div class='S'></div>
    <div class='S'></div>
</div>
```

Как можно найти, например, только 2 или только 3 по счету `class='N'`. Классов N не обязательно будет 3 на странице. Так, например, я пробую найти 2 по счету `class='N'` и в нем перебрать все `class='S'`, но это не работает. Получается,что `class='S'` ищется на всей странице, а не конкретно во втором `class='N'`. Кто знает, как можно решить проблему?

```
two = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='N'][2]")
 i = two.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='S']")
     for j in i:
         j.click()
         time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: `"//div[@class='N'][3]"` ?

Comment: не получается так

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME  дополнил вопрос с учетом вашей рекомендации, все равно так не получается..

Comment: если у вас всегда одинаковое количество элементов, то вы можете взять отрезок  списка

Comment: не, количество элементов всегда разное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//div[@class='N'][index]//div[@class='S']
```

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста, а как можно переделать эту строку с учетом find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'N')[1]/*/div[@class='S']")[:5]

Comment: потому что иначе появляется предупреждение об устаревшем методе find_elements_by_xpath